# set innerHTML to variable

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code as the body of an HTML file...

```
<body>
<ol>
<li id="x1"> Item 1 </li>
<li> Item 2 </li>
</ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
var ds = "new text";
document.getElementById("x1").innerHTML = ds;   
</script>
</body>
```

But for some reason, the innerHTML line isn't changing "Item 1" to "new text." Not sure what's wrong here.

EDIT: I'm using Firefox version 10.0.02, no errors are coming up in the console, and this is the only thing that's using that ID on the page.

Comment: Which Browser are you testing on?

Comment: are you getting/checking for any errors in the console?

Comment: Literally pasted your code and clicked run: http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/xU54w/

Comment: any js errors in, for example, chrome console? syntax looks correct to me

Comment: This should work. The script might execute before loading DOM. That might be a problem. What is your browser and version?

Comment: The code should work since the script is coming after the element in the DOM.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with whose ID value is "x1"? If so, then that's your problem.

Comment: Testing it in Firefox 10.0.02, and I'm not getting any errors shown. This is the only thing that I'm using that has that id tag as well.

Comment: @user1238565 The only thing I can think of is that Javascript is disabled in your browser. Please tell us if paislee's jsfiddle works. it does for the rest of us, even when using Firefox 10.0.2!

Comment: The jsfiddle works, and I have javascript enabled. I can get the element to change text if I set it directly as text (.innerHTML = "some text";) but not if I set it as a variable.

I've tried this on two computers now, so it's not something that's wrong with my local settings.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Do you have any other pieces of Javascript in your page, maybe using `ds` in other ways? And does it behave differently on other browsers?

Comment: I just tried IE8 and Chrome with the same file and they all behave the same. There is other JavaScript on the page, but nothing that interacts with that list item or the list at all. The rest of the JavaScript was added after I gave up on figuring out this problem on my own anyway.

Comment: I scrapped the html file and started over. Was too small of a project to keep fretting over. No problems now but no idea what it was earlier.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use JQuery because making such task with jquery is a peice of cake $("#x1").innerHTML(ds);

Comment: so is not using jquery in this case... it's a one line snippet and in this case you don't need to include a library.  Chances are the issue would make the snippet fail in both cases.

Comment: jquery is so light and it is compatible on all browsers so using it will allow you to be sure 100% that your code will run correctly.

Comment: The scientist means that if the OP's code fails, replacing it with jQuery will likely fail too, for the same reason. So it's better to look for said reason than to replace something that should work with something else. No criticism of jQuery was intended.